# De-tropicalization of multiplication

Tags: limits, functions, tropical-geometry

Does there exist a function $f(x)$ so that
$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\log \,f(e^{tx})}{t} = x^2 ~~~ ? $$

**Motivation:** The "*tropicalization*" of a function $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is the function
$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t} \, \log \, f(e^{tx_1},\dots,e^{tx_n}) $$

This gives the usual "max-plus" tropical algebra: if you take $f(x,y) = x+y$, then this limit is $\mathrm{max}(x,y)$, and if you take $f(x,y) = xy$, then this limit is $x+y$. I'm wondering if it's known if there is any function whose tropicalization is ordinary multiplication?

In other words, is there some $f(x,y)$ so that $\lim \frac{1}{t} \, \log \, f(e^{tx},e^{ty}) = xy$ ? The original question above (in just the single variable $x$) would just be akin to taking $y=x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a function cannot exist.
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\log \,f(e^{tx})}{t} = F(x)
$$
for all $x > 0$ implies that
$$
 F(ax) = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\log \,f(e^{tax})}{t}
= a \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\log \,f(e^{atx})}{at} = aF(x)
$$
for all $a > 0$.

The function $F(x) = x^2$ does not satisfy this homogeneity condition.